# Estratégia de Geração Id Hibernate no PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jee

Tenho um sistema em JEE7 com Hibernate e banco de dados PostgreSQL, as tabelas estão com geração de Id auto pelo Hibernate:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
```

O que acontece é que o Hibernate gera um índice único para todas as tabelas, por exemplo, um id=657 para Cliente e o próximo id=658 para Produto, .....

Como seria possível gerar um índice, de forma automática, para cada tabela?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Alternativamente é também possível utilizar uma coluna do tipo [`SERIAL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) combinada com uma estratégia de geração `IDENTITY` do lado do Hibernate.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "meu_id", columnDefinition = "serial")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```

Comment: Desta forma o Hibernate vai "cuidar de tudo", criar o campo e auto incrementar? Não vou precisar criar um Sequence no Postgresql?

Comment: Na verdade o Postgre vai cuidar de tudo. O tipo `serial` é equivalente ao uso de uma sequência (porém bem mais sucinto).

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a melhor forma é você criar o *sequence* para cada tabela na base de dados e depois setar na model para usar ele:

Para criar a sequence, use:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_empresa START 1;
```

Para dizer ao hibernate para usar esta sequence:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id_empresa")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_empresa")
private Long idEmpresa;
```